# Sucess local debugging but 502 error in when deplying teams messaging extension app

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I'm developing a messaging extension app using the Teams Toolkit following examples in the docs.

The app is pretty simple, all it really does is call a third party API and returns results. Everything works fine when debugging, but as soon as I try to deploy the app it fails to function, returning a 502 error when the search query is executed.

I've tried adding AllowedDomains to the app manifest with no luck.

Comment: Please re-verify your application configuration in deployed app, manifest etc.

Comment: Hi Chetan :) I've done this and it's reporting everything is valid. Please can you advise further?

Comment: Hello @edh - Have you enables the Teams channel in your Azure bot and added proper messaging endpoint configuration in Azure bot?

Comment: Hi again Chetan. I've enabled the Teams channels in the Azure bot yes. I'm not sure what you mean by proper messaging endpoint configuration, and I'm not sure why this would be needed, and why the app would function OK in debugging. The docs are unclear. Please could you explain?

Comment: Messaging endpoint configuration means the endpoint where you will get your request. For e.g. https://6785-103-132-3-80.ngrok.io/api/messages